# Skipping Initial Login Page with Django Allauth

Tags: python, django, django-allauth

I am using [django-allauth](https://django-allauth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) for a website. I have integrated Google login through it. Currently, when I access the login, I get the standard sign-in page, on which is a link to sign in through Google. What is the best way to skip the standard sign-in page and go straight to the Google one (as in the one on accounts.google.com...)? All login is done through Google, so I don't need to see the initial page, just the Google one.

Should I override the provided template to just redirect? Or is there a better way to configure it?

Answer (score 3):

I know it is a old topic, but I had the same issue and could not find a Solution on the web because of that I want to share my best solution. First of all I created a new socialaccounts template, so that this one will be taken instead of the original allauth template. For that you need to create a new folder and html file as followed:
`"template->socialaccount-> login.html"`

Thats the page you want to skip. To do that I simply inserted a javascript which, submits the form as soon the page is loaded:

```
  {%load socialaccount%}

<body onload="document.forms['google_login'].submit()">

<p>You should be redirect to the Google login page in some seconds otherwise use the button below.</p>


<form method="post" name= "google_login">
  {% csrf_token %}
  <button type="submit">Continue</button>
</form>

</body>
```

Maybe this helps someone else.

Best regards

Answer (score 0):

I just copied the address to which the existing Django-template hyperlink pointed, and then created a view to redirect all logins to that link with the correct return page. My URL pattern:

`url(r'^login/$', views.redirectToGoogle, name="rediect_to_Google")`

My view was:

```
GOOGLE_LOGIN_URL_PREFIX = '/accounts/google/login/?'

def redirectToGoogle(request):
    coming_from = request.GET.get("next", "/manage")
    url_params = {
        "process": "login",
        "next": coming_from
    }
    suffix = urllib.parse.urlencode(url_params)
    return redirect(GOOGLE_LOGIN_URL_PREFIX + suffix)
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is:
In `settings.py` add `SOCIALACCOUNT_LOGIN_ON_GET=True`

From the [django-allauth docs](https://django-allauth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configuration.html):

"SOCIALACCOUNT_LOGIN_ON_GET (=False)
Controls whether or not the endpoints for initiating a social login (for example, “/accounts/google/login/”) require a POST request to initiate the handshake. For security considerations, it is strongly recommended to require POST requests."

Comment: For those looking for the specific security reasons of why to not use `SOCIALACCOUNT_LOGIN_ON_GET = True`, see the [Changelog for django-allauth](https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth/blob/main/ChangeLog.rst#security-notice-3) and [Google's blog post about open redirect abuse](https://developers.google.com/search/blog/2009/01/open-redirect-urls-is-your-site-being).